# Java regex on TSV for capturing groups

Tags: java, regex, csv

I am trying to use a regex on a TSV to get every element into a capturing group (sounds simple, and I think it should be).  Basically I have a 58 column TSV file, and I want to get each value into a group.  So for a regex, I'm literally just doing `(.+)\t` 58 times but I can't seem to grab the values.

Is this the best way to do it?  I want to later on access the capturing groups by their index.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easier to analyze this TSV file line by line and just split this line on \t character. This solution will be more elegant.
If you really want to use regex please look [here](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html) - this article describes recursive regex expression.